# Ignore null in search query using udt

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, search, filter

I'm working on a filter function and I'm struggling with Sql.

I have a proc with this logic.

```
    RIGHT JOIN @filterQuery as fq
        ON (fq.Bpm = c.BPM OR fq.Bpm IS NULL) 
        AND (fq.Price  >= c.Price OR fq.Price IS NULL)
        AND (fq.GenreTypeId = g.Id OR fq.GenreTypeId IS NULL)
        AND (fq.KeyTypeId = k.Id OR fq.KeyTypeId IS NULL)
        AND (fq.TrackTypeId = t.Id OR fq.TrackTypeId IS NULL)
```

My test code looks like this

```
DECLARE     @filters AS dbo.FilterTable
                    ,@PageIndex int = 0
                    ,@PageSize int = 10


        INSERT INTO @filters (Bpm,Price,GenreTypeId,KeyTypeId,TrackTypeId)
                
        VALUES (126,null,null,null,null),(76,null,null,null,2)

        EXECUTE dbo.PROC     @filters
                            ,@PageIndex
                            ,@PageSize
```

Now my issue is that when I run my code my result set looks SOMETHING like this.

```
Bpm  Price  GenreTypeId  KeyTypeId  TrackTypeId
126  5.99       1            1           1 
126  4.99       1            1           1
```

This makes sense because there are no records with **BPM** *76* and **TrackTypeId** *2* but because the first set of values for **BPM** *126* is NULL at **TrackTypeId** it does not filter for **TrackTypeId** 2 from the second set of values.

I need my result set to be **empty** since there are no **records** in the database for **any** *TrackTypeId 2*. Is this possible?

EDIT : I would like my result set to be empty BECAUSE there is no data with trackTypeId 2. but currently it's giving me all 126 BPM since trackTypeId is null for this particular filter.

Comment: This does not make sense? You are passing 2 complete filter conditions, 1 for BPB 126 and TrackType null and one for BPM 76 and TrackTypeId 2. You do not explain in your question anywhere how 2 separate filter conditions should be combined. Why don't you just pass TrackTypeId 2 into the first filter condition?

Comment: the filter conditions are coming from the front end where a user might choose to filter for 126 BPM and then also click on 76 BPM AND TrackTypeId 2. At this point, the result set would be basically all 126 BPM which I do not want.

Comment: So what do you want? How do you want to combine the 2 separate search conditions? Why would they select both 76 AND 126? And what should the result be?

Comment: @DaleK I suspect OP actually needs a separate filter table for each separate column condition, in other words `AND` semantics per column to be searched

Comment: would you give us your desired result set? I don't know what do you want

Comment: If you right join to your filter table, your resultset will ALWAYS include those rows from the filter table. That contradicts your desired goal. If you pass an empty table to your procedure (which one might assume equates logically to "select everything"), then it will never return any rows. Seems you need to spend some additional time thinking about your goal and requirements. I get the impression you might be trying to use one filter table when you need one table for each filterable column.

Comment: @Charlieface so I do have another proc where I'm using an UDT per filter. Is this the right approach to what I want?

Comment: @GGG my desired result set would be empty because there is no data with trackTypeId at 2.

Comment: @SMor I do have another proc using a UDT per filter, but I ran into the same issues. Do I need to look into coalesce ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Judging by the logic you are trying to achieve, what you need is a separate table type per filter column.** You also should have logic of the following style

```sql
WHERE (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @columnFilters) OR column IN (SELECT * FROM @columnFilters))
```

I normally keep a few standard one-column table types of various data types in my database for this kind of purpose.

```sql
WHERE (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Bpm) OR
    c.Bpm IN (SELECT * FROM @Bpm))
  AND (c.Price >= @Price OR @Price IS NULL)
  AND (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @GenreTypeId) OR
    g.Id IN (SELECT * FROM @GenreTypeId))
  AND (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @KeyTypeId) OR
    k.Id IN (SELECT * FROM @KeyTypeId))
  AND (NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @TrackTypeId) OR
    t.Id IN (SELECT * FROM @TrackTypeId))
```

Note the use of a scalar variable for `@Price`, because you can just put in the minimum you want for that, as the condition is an inequality `>=`.

If you really did want to use a table for that also, you could do this:

```sql
(NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @Price) OR
    c.Price >= ANY(SELECT * FROM @GenreTypeId))
```

---

I strongly suggest you look at either `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` or dynamic SQL for such a query, if you are trying to hit indexes.

Comment: for the price, if I still want to keep it a table and not a scalar variable, how would I reformat the IN statement to match >=?

Comment: Have added that for you

Comment: is there a huge difference between using ANY like you did and how I ended up using it? Also I was getting errors about "subquery returned more than 1 value" so I added the second WHERE statement.                                                                          
    `c.Price <= (SELECT * FROM @Price AS p WHERE p.Price IS NOT NULL))`

Comment: Exactly why I used `ANY`, because of the multiple value problem. You could also write it like this, it's exactly the same under the hood `EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @GenreTypeId t WHERE c.Price >= t.val)`. But as I said, it makes no sense to do any of this with an inequality: just pick the highest value and put that into a scalar variable